# WindowsDeviceGroup claims

Tags: windows, device

ADFS 2016 supports a new claim type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsdevicegroup" which contains the Windows devices group SIDs. How may I cast the claims on a simple claims aware ASP.Net Application ? I am on VS 2015, .Net 4.6. What are the minimum requirements to grab this claim type and its value from ADFS so I may use it. Any code snippet would be highly appreciated.

I need help in getting the code that can do something like this but for a Windows Device -

ClaimType - http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsdevicegroup , ClaimValue - S-1-21-5-xxxx-xyyyy-zzzzzz.

Where S-1-21-5-xxxx-xyyyy-zzzzzz is the SID of a Group the computer is member of.
Also, Any chance that this claim type may be used with ADFS 2012R2 ?

Answer (score 1):

This uses the compound authentication pattern that was released as part of WS2012 Active Directory. See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36830 for details on it. Look for the compound authentication section. Then you need to pass the necessary claims by modifying the ADFS's claims provider trust for "Active Directory". Now you have those claims that can be consumed by a downstream application.

Note that this works through Kerberos. So, only if the client is inside the corporate network with line of sight to the a correctly enabled domain controller, will this use case light up.

Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: I did this - 1. Domain Controller GPO - "KDC support for claims, compound authentication and Kerberos armoring enabled" 2. Clients configured for Kerberos client support for claims, compound authentication and Kerberos armoring enabled. 3. Added the rule set in ADFS Claims Provider trust - "c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsdevicegroup"]
 => issue(claim = c);
"... My asp.Net App claims aware shows all claims except "windowsdevicegroup" ... what am I still missing ?

Comment: Also, did set CompoundIdentitySupported = $true for the on-prem web server hosting the web site. All machines in same domain as well...still no go :( ...am I missing to make the web site Windows Device Claims aware as per last rule of the guide you shared ? if, yes... how can I make a simple web form capture windowsdevicegroup claims ?